# WPF: Changing DataTemplate in combobox based on, void collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a collection `ObservableCollection <FeatureLayer> FeatureLayerList` and `ObservableCollection <TextBlock> TextBlock`. 
I need a DataTemplate, for `Combobox`, to display items from `FeatureLayerList`, and DataTemplate to display items from the `TextBlock`. 
Show DataTempales need so that if an empty collection `FeatureLayerList` show DataTemplate for collection `TextBlock` which is one element at a click which should give you a form which will be added items in the collection `FeatureLayerList`, after the items in the collection were added, you must close the form by which add items took place and show DataTemplate for collection FeatureLayerList with added elements. 
I do not understand the kinds of DataTemplates for my collections, and how to switch between them.

Explain to me how to use the DataTemplate for Combobox, and how to switch between DataTemplates depending on conditions.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="FeatureLayerComboBox" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" Margin="0, 2, 0, 10" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFeatureLayer}" ItemsSource="{Binding FeatureLayerList}" Width="258" Height="22" />

public ObservableCollection<FeatureLayer> FeatureLayerList
        {
            get
            {
                return featureLayerList;
            }
            set
            {
                featureLayerList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FeatureLayerList");
            }
        }
public FeatureLayer SelectedFeatureLayer
        {
            get { return selectedFeatureLayer; }
            set
            {
                selectedFeatureLayer = value;
                ShapeType.GeometryType = selectedFeatureLayer.ShapeType;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedFeatureLayer");
                OnPropertyChanged("IsEnabledSendButton");
            }
        }

public ObservableCollection<TextBlock> TextBlocks
{
    get 
    {
        textBlocks = new ObservableCollection<TextBlock>() {
        new TextBlock { Text="Create...", Foreground = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#00A6FF")) } };
        return  textBlocks;
    }
}

private static ObservableCollection<FeatureLayer> featureLayerList;
private ObservableCollection<TextBlock> TextBlocks textBlocks;
```

Comment: Including code in your question will greatly improve your chances of getting help on SO.  Please read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for the site's standards for asking a question.

Comment: Share what you tried and post some code. Also look into DataTemplateSelector.

Comment: I do not understand how I need to create DataTemplates, and switch between them depending on whether I have the items in the collection FeatureLayerList. 
I'm new to WPF. If not difficult to explain in detail what I should do!